# Is it a right way to use unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a raw pointer and would like to have the callback owns it. I come up with this code:

```
A* a = new A();
dosomething(callback(unique_ptr<A>(a).get()))

// The callback always takes a raw pointer.
void callback(A* a) {
}
```

Is it the right way to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you expecting your smart pointer to do in this situation?

Comment: Since `callback` dosen't return anything, you cannot call `dosomething(callback(...))`. Since `callback` should be a callback, you may want to do something like this: `sosomething([a](){ /* callback */ });`? Maybe I can help if I know the type which is expected by `dosomething`.

Comment: @Kupiakos: You wrote the answer I was about to write, as a comment. I suggest you make it an answer. ;-) Well perhaps add some advice about also how to do things in a good way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `callback` doesn't own it. It will, however, be destroyed after `dosomething` finishes.

If you constructed `dosomething` to take a callback and an `A *`, then had `dosomething` call `callback` with the given `A *` as an argument, it could work as long as the `unique_ptr` created is only used during its execution.

Example:

```
void callback(A *a)
{
    if (!a) return;
    std::cout << "Got A " << a->name() << std::endl;
}

void dosomething(const std::function<void(A *)> &func, std::unique_ptr<A> obj)
{
    std::cout << "Doing some operation..." << std::endl;
    func(obj.get());
}

int main()
{
    dosomething(callback, std::make_unique<A>());
}
```

Comment: `std::make_unique<A>()` would be better than `std::unique_ptr<A>(new A{})` (even more when you pass it to function taking several arguments).

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't know about that function, adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the whole thing and use `std::shared_ptr`:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
callback(a);
```

this will require you to declare `callback` as one which gets `std::shared_ptr` at the first place.

of course, It's a bit odd that `callback` doesn't return anything..